# Chunking an iterable

Tags: java, iterable

I have a method to get a load of objects from a database, which returns an `Iterable`.

For now, I am loading a resultset from a database, building objects from it and populating a collection with those objects.

Obviously, I'm memory constrained as to how much data can be loaded using this method and if I run out Bad Things Happen.

I'd like to modify the implementation to chunk data from the database instead of getting it all at once and then expose the resulting objects to the client through the `Iterable` interface. My database drivers can do their bit, so my first thought is a custom implementation of `Iterable` that does this.

Is this a good approach? It strikes me as something that might already be supported in the runtime or libraries - not involving ORM solutions please.

Comment: Is there a reason you'd want to implement an `Iterable` and not just an `Iterator`? The later would probably be easier as you wouldn't have to add the ability to re-start the iteration.

Comment: Good point - no reason at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally the simplest solution that I can think of is to implement a `Iterator` as a thin wrapper around a `ResultSet`. That has several advantages:

- You don't need to provide reproducable SQL statements (you can stream non-sorted results, for example)
- You don't need to rely on [repeatable read](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ), which can be costly
- If your JDBC driver is good, then you can just use its streaming result features (warning: some JDBC drivers always grab the full result as soon as you start iterating over it!)
- You don't need to implement re-starting the `Iterator` (`Iterable.iterator()` could be called twice, which makes this complicated).
- Not "remembering" previously returned data means that the memory requirement can be held pretty low

It also has a few disadvantages:

- your `Iterator` implementation effectively becomes an external resources, since it binds a JDBC resource: it must be "closed" in some way, making it harder to use
- if the `Iterator` hangs around for a longer time, then that *also* lets a JDBC `Connection` hang around, which might be needed elsewhere (you can't return it to the pool, until the `Iterator` is done).

An alternative way is to implement a `List` (or `Collection`) that lazily restores fractions of its data as needed. This can be nicer to use, but is quite a lot more complicated to build (correctly!). Also, if memory constraints are important, then you'll need to add a mechanism to discard previously-restored objects.

Comment: And an alternative way (as you mentioned) would be to remember the offset and then use `SELECT ... LIMIT M,N` to "scroll" to necessary position. Of course, the information might change over the time (another transaction has inserted new rows or deleted), but this approach allows you to close JDBC connection allowing the DB server to handle more transactions per minute.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented Joachim's suggested approach in one of my applications.  I implemented a `DestroyableIterator` interface that included a `destroy()` method, which in the case of the `ResultSet` wrapper implementation closed the `ResultSet`.  (Some libraries provide this interface but I didn't see the point of introducing a library dependency for the sake of a 3 line interface definition.)

I also caught `SQLException`s and translated them into (unchecked) Spring `DataAccessException`s in order to propagate them through Iterator's `next()` and `hasNext()` methods.

The point regarding holding onto resources is a valid one; I was in control of the application code using the `DestroyableIterator` and so had various time-out mechanisms to avoid holding onto the live `ResultSet` for too long.

Comment: In Java 7 and upwards, I'd suggest implementing `AutoClosable` and using `close()` instead of `destroy()` for extra arm-block sweetness.

Comment: Only thing is you'd then have to test for AutoCloseable using instanceof.  Perhaps worth uniting the two interfaces as AutoCloseableIterator?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean: Let `DestroyableIterator` implement `AutoClosable` (at which point, I'd rename it to `AutoClosableIterator` ;-))